# Property [name] does not exist on this collection instance in Laravel 6

Tags: php, mysql, laravel-6

I am trying to show single books in my application. All the data, that is in the "books" table can be shown, but nothing else. If I want to show all of my books, I can display connected data from other tables as well, but if I just want to show the data of 1 single book I cannot seem to get it to work and I cannot find the problem.

**BookController:**

```
public function show($id)
    {
        $book = Book::findOrFail($id);
        $languages = Language::all();
        $genres = Genre::all();
        $authors = Author::all();
        $publishers = Publisher::all();

        return view('books/show', compact('book', 'languages', 'genres','authors','publishers'));
    }
```

**show.blade.php:**

```
@extends('layout')


@section('title')
<title>Alle Bücher</title>
@section('content')
<style>
    .uper {
        margin-top: 40px;
    }
</style>
<div class="uper">
    @if(session()->get('success'))
    <div class="alert alert-success">
        {{ session()->get('success') }}
    </div><br />
    @endif
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-12 margin-tb">
            <div class="pull-left">
                <h2> {{ $book->title }}</h2>
            </div>
            <div class="pull-right">
                <a class="btn btn-primary" href="{{ route('books.index') }}"> Back</a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12">
            <div class="form-group">
                <strong>ID:</strong>
                {{ $book->id }}
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12">
            <div class="form-group">
                <strong>Details:</strong>
                {{ $book->title }}
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12">
            <div class="form-group">
                <strong>Autor(en):</strong>
                @foreach($book->authors as $author)
                {{$book->authors->name}}
                @endforeach
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12">
            <div class="form-group">
                <strong>Jahr:</strong>
                {{ $book->year }}
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12">
            <div class="form-group">
                <strong>Verlag(e):</strong>
                @foreach($book->publishers as $publisher)
                {{$publisher->name}}
                @endforeach
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12">
            <div class="form-group">
                <strong>Genre(s):</strong>
                @foreach($book->genres as $genre)
                {{$genre->name}}
                @endforeach
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12">
            <div class="form-group">
                <strong>Sprache:</strong>
                {{$book->language->name}}
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12">
            <div class="form-group">
                <strong>ISBN:</strong>
                {{ $book->isbn }}
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12">
            <div class="form-group">
                <strong>Seitenzahl:</strong>
                {{ $book->pages }}
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    @endsection
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a logic error; `{{ $book->authors->name }}` is wrong. You're correctly looping `$book->authors`, but then referencing the wrong variable. Fix as such:

```
@foreach($book->authors as $author)
  {{ $author->name }}
@endforeach
```

Note; You did this correctly with `$book->publishers as $publisher` and `$book->genres as $genre` later in the code, so check your consistency.